# Running a one time job on Azure Container Apps

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I'm trying to figure out what the easiest way of running a "one time job" on Azure Container Apps is.

I know that it can be done with Azure Container Instances or Azure Kubernetes Service, but is there something similar for ACA?

Ideally, I'm looking for some kind of cli command like `az containerapps run --image <some-image>` that can run in an environment and is cleaned up when it has finished running.

Is that possible?

Comment: There are some options to run some background task as describe here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/background-processing?tabs=bash

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, but that's not really what I was looking for. I got an answer from the ACA team. They are working on "jobs" which will solve this. https://github.com/microsoft/azure-container-apps/issues/446

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now run [Jobs in Azure Container Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/jobs?tabs=azure-cli#compare-container-apps-and-jobs)

You have different type of triggers available:

- Manual jobs triggered on-demand using cli, ARM/Bicep or from the portal
- Scheduled jobs triggered based on a CRON expression.
- Event-driven jobs triggered using KEDA scalers.